# Google Analytics Regex - Matching Specific Words, but Not Others

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I don't usually use Regex. I'm working on Google Analytics Goals and I want to create a step in the funnel that will match URLs containing `/resource/` and the word `ebook` or `report`, but do not include `thank` or `thanks`.

It would match:

```
/resource/example-ebook-request
/resource/research-report-2018/
```

It would not match:

```
/resource/example-ebook-request/thank-you/
/resource/research-report-2018/thanks/
/some-other-ebook-no-resource-subfolder/
```

I'm having a hard time getting the combination of this correct in a way that will work for Google Analytics since it doesn't support look behind. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `\/resource\/[^\/]*(?:ebook|report)[^\/]*\/?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvVZWI/3)

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thank you, Matt! If you don't mind, could you explain why it works a little bit? I follow most of it, but not how it is excluding URLs with "thank" in them. Would love to learn.

Comment: @AndrewGMarketing it does so by asserting the end of the string. Depending on your input, this may not work in all cases.

Comment: @AndrewGMarketing, this regex doesn't exclude "thank". Based on the urls given as samples in the post, I deduced a pattern that there should be only one path segment after `/resource/` and that should contain either `ebook` or `report` ending with a `/` (optional).